# How can I authenticate a user against an AWS cognito user pool in react native?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS cognito user pool with some users and I am trying to obtain a token for a user in my react native app. But as soon as I reference the aws cognito javascript sdk in my react native app it crashes. I have successfully obtained the token in react app. Here is my code in the react app. I am looking for help to migrate this simple piece of code to react native.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser,
  CognitoUserPool,
  CognitoUserAttribute
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { token: null };
  }

  getToken = function() {
    var authenticationData = {
        Username : 'testuser',
        Password : 'test123',
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId : 'ap-southeast-2_412', // Your user pool id here
        ClientId : '123' // Your client id here
    };
    var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username : 'testuser',
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            let tok = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
            console.log('access token + ' + tok);
            this.setState({ token: tok });
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        newPasswordRequired: function(userAtt, reqAtt)
        {
          console.log(userAtt);
          console.log(reqAtt);
        }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
          <button onClick={ this.getToken.bind(this) }>Get Token</button>
        <p>
          Token: { this.state.token }
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I had to use this module: https://github.com/AirLabsTeam/react-native-aws-cognito-js

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post for this a while ago: https://shellmonger.com/2017/05/15/authenticating-react-native-to-aws-cognito-user-pools/ - it includes sample code for how to do this.

Comment: I followed your instructions in the blog but I am now getting an error object is not a constructor at this line in CognitoUserPool.js

    this.client = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-19', region });

Comment: Have you taken a look at the code in the linked GitHub repository?  I just re-checked that code and it is working, so it's likely something that has changed in the underlying library or a small typo that you made when adjusting the library to be compatible with react native.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new library from AWS called AWS Amplify to assist with this: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

It contains an `Auth` module with specific React Native extensions that you can install via npm:

```
npm install aws-amplify-react-native
```

You will need to link your project: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/quick_start.md#react-native-development

From there you can either call APIs directly or use the built in Components for wrapping your App.